# sudo with password in one command line?

Tags: shell, sudo

On busy days, I'd like to run

```
$ ./configure && make && sudo make install && halt
```

on the night and go to bed, hoping the application would automatically be installed. But what I see the next day is the screen where sudo asks me for the password. So how could I run sudo with password in one command line, or is there any other method to do this?

Comment: You need `halt` to run as root.

Comment: Doesn't `sudo` have a 15-minute timeout? Couldn't you run, say, `sudo ls` or something similar, enter your password, and then run the above command, having `sudo` privileges still active? (I can't test this at the moment, otherwise I'd post this as an answer.)

Comment: The timeout on `sudo` is configurable. Security-conscious people (aka paranoid, like me) set it to zero... :-)

Comment: Also see [Prompt for sudo password and programmatically elevate privilege in bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28791/56041), [How to enter password only once in a bash script needing sudo](https://askubuntu.com/q/711580), [Request root privilege from within a script](https://askubuntu.com/q/746350), [Create a sudo user in script with no prompt for password...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43853533/608639), [How to prompt user for sudo password?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47538572/608639), etc

Comment: `sudo -v`; is the easity way to get sudo to prompt with as a noop.
@Matt

Answer (score 322, accepted):

Yes, use the `-S` switch which reads the password from STDIN:

```
$echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

So for your case it would look like this:

```
$./configure && make && echo <password> | sudo -S make install && halt
```

of course, replace `<password>` with your password.

Comment: Obviously, one would not want to run this if there is any danger of someone else seeing the password in the shell history.

Comment: looking for quick ways to run privileged commands on a remote host and this works thanks.

Comment: If you decided to use the 'echo <password> | sudo -S' option, to avoid exposing the password on the command history, start the command with a SPACE character. Of course, the best option is to pipe the password from a secure file.

Comment: You might want to use that if you have the password in a $VARIABLE (that you could have provision with sops for instance)

Comment: 9 years later and still works like a charm :)

Comment: piping it in also works without `-S`

Comment: Why I'm getting "Sorry, try again" then "sudo: no password was provided" whit the above method? My password contains $, but putting \ in front of the $ doesn't work.

Comment: I works in ubuntu 2004.

Comment: @NeilWang Try this: echo "password" | sudo -S bash -c "the-command-goes-over-here"

Comment: perhaps one should use  `--stdin` instead to make it easier to remember.

Answer (score 40):

Set HISTIGNORE to "*sudo -S*"

```
$ export HISTIGNORE='*sudo -S*'
```

Then pass your password safely to sudo:

```
$ echo "your_password" | sudo -S -k <command>
```

"HISTIGNORE" means to not save this command into the history.  That is the history in memory or "~/.bash_history" file.

For example, the below will safely pipe your password to the sudo command, without
retaining a history of your password.

“-S”, means to use stdin for the password,

“-k” means to ignore cached credentials to force sudo 
to always ask.  This is for consistent behavior.

```
$ export HISTIGNORE='*sudo -S*'
$ echo "<your_password>" | sudo -S -k whoami
$ echo "<your_password>" | sudo -S -k cat /etc/shadow
$ echo "<your_password>" | sudo -S -k bash /tmp/myscript.sh
```

The downside to the above method is that if you want to see the commands you ran in the history later on they won't be there.  Another method is to update the sudo authentication credential cache (default is enabled with 5 minutes timeout), then run the sudo separately.  But the downside of this is that you'll need to be aware of the 5 minute cache.

For example:

```
$ export HISTIGNORE='*sudo -S*'
$ echo "<your_password>" | sudo -S -v
$ sudo whoami
$ echo "<your_password>" | sudo -S -v
$ sudo cat /etc/shadow
$ echo "<your_password>" | sudo -S -v
$ sudo /tmp/myscript.sh
```

Note I ran a sudo before each command to ensure that the sudo cache is updated, as the default is 5 mintues.  Yes, whoami shouldn't take 5 minutes, but I figure might as well have it run before each command for consistency.  You could also put "export HISTIGNORE='*sudo -S*'" in your ~/.bashrc file, then load it with ". ~/.bashrc" or logoff then login.  However, I'm thinking using this for scripting purposes, so I'll keep it at the top of all my scripts for best security practices.  Setting "echo "" | sudo -S -v" to a variable instead might also be a good idea, then just run the variable before each command that needs root privileges, see Janar's comment.  "John T"'s comment should also include the "-k" parameter, as if you run "sudo -S" without "-k" and sudo authentication cache already has your credentials (and is still valid, default sudo authentication cache is 5 minutes) then bash will run your password as a command instead, which is bad.

Comment: Just as a small note on making things not available in the history, run your command with a single space at the front of it. For some reason this causes history to ignore it.

Comment: If you put your password into a command-line parameter, then it will be visible to all in the output of _ps_. Better to put it in a file and use indirection (`sudo -S -v <FILE`), or use here strings if _bash_ is your shell (`sudo -S -v <<<'<your_password>'`)

Answer (score 28):

You can do this too:

```
sudo -S <<< "password" command
```

Comment: only this one works for me in mac os.

Comment: only this works in WinSCP shell. Thanks!

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me in ZSH.

Answer (score 14):

You could also configure sudo with `visudo` to allow you user to use make as sudo without password.

```
User_Alias USERS = your_user
Cmnd_Alias CMDS = /usr/bin/make
USERS ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: CMDS
```

Comment: I figured out no need to declare aliases. Add `my_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/your_command` is OK. Remember to add it to the end to overwrite other configs.

Answer (score 13):

Several of the other solutions have the disadvantage that they unnecessarily run `./configure` and `make` as root.

This is a bit convoluted, but it should work:

```
sudo sh -c "su $USER -c ./configure && su $USER -c make && make install && halt"
```

Note the use of double quotes to allow `$USER` to be expanded by the (non-root) shell.

I might also add a `sleep 60` before the `halt` command. I've sometimes done things like this, expecting the command to run for a long time, but something goes wrong and it terminates immediately; the `sleep` lets me kill the command before the system shuts down. Or you can use `shutdown` with a time argument.

Answer (score 12):

You could replace your command line with this:

`$sudo su`

`$./configure && make && make install && halt`

You will be prompted for your password immediately, then the rest of the commands will run as superuser.

Comment: an alternate (and probably preferred) version of this: `sudo sh -c "./configure && make && make install && halt"`

Comment: But then wouldn't all the generated compile files have the superuser permissions? This would prevent you from running ./configure && make as a regular user later.

Comment: Yes, user45909, you're quite right. I have personally never rerun ./configure && make except after downloading an update of the main package anyway, but I'm probabably not typical.

Comment: Still great for all kinds of general use, such as copying mysql databases

Answer (score 5):

Note, I've found that method doesn't work on an older version of sudo, specifically "Sudo version 1.6.7p5":

```
$ echo "<your_password>" | sudo -S -k whoami
```

Where as this method does work on older and new versions sudo:

```
$ echo "<your_password>" | sudo -S -v
$ sudo whoami
```

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Darren DeHaven : Could you please explain how this become answer for the question asked here?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take more care, you could make a script, change the permissions of the file so only root can read and edit and then just run it.

Example:
1)  Create a file:

```
gedit ~/.easy.install
```

2) Paste this and save:

```
./configure && make && echo <password> | sudo -S make install && halt
```

3) Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x ~/.easy.install
```

4) Change the permissions of the file so only root can read and edit it:

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.easy.install
```

5) Run:

```
~/.easy.install
```

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: echo <password> will still show up in the process list and if someone gets lucky with ps aux at the exact right moment, they can see the password in clear text. Better to save the password to a file and use < to redirect from the file into sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up sudo like that is dangerous if someone happened to see the fact that sudo requires no password on your account. Unless you know what you are doing, don't do that. I've had it happen at my local A+ Training program with my experimental computer one too many times... -_-

What John T. said sounds good though, except there still is the risk of finding the password in shell history. What CarlF said sounds better, but if one command fails, the computer will still be running with superuser privileges.

Answer (score 1):

In many situation you wouldn't want to pipe the password, but to keep sudo **credentials refreshed**:

```
refreshPermissions () {
    local pid="${1}"

    while kill -0 "${pid}" 2> /dev/null; do
        sudo -v
        sleep 10
    done
}

refreshPermissions "$$" &
```

Then if a **command** needs root permissions within your program just do:

```
sudo [command]
```

And no password will be requested.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I  do quite the same as John T answered on Nov 9 '09 at 2:47, I've also improved mine according to guidance of his answer, thanks.

Difference is that I tend make use of variables, something like:

```
AutoSuDo=$" $echo pass | sudo -S";
# Change AutoSuDo to something else.
# Note that string starts with space,
# useful only if used as first command in line
```

In that way I can easily use mine variable instead of sudo,

```
$AutoSuDo apt-get update;
```

That comes quite handy with some longer scripts. I mainly make use of these for personal computers of others, that I have to maintain.

I also recommend to pay attention on:

- desgua answer on Apr 19 '11 at 23:56
- user224306 comment on May 14 '13 at 17:38 for John T answer on Nov 9 '09 at 2:47

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved.
For example, to the user root:

```
echo -e 'password\npassword\n' | sudo passwd root
```

Comment: What does -e flag do, @jerson Martinez?

Comment: The -e flag for echo allows it to interpret certain sequences as having special meanings.