# Run part of a bash script as a different user

Tags: linux, bash, user

I am in Ubuntu 9.04. Is there a way to make part of a script run as a different (non-root) user? If it helps, the part to be run as a different user occurs at the end of the script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto switch / chage user id witin a bash script to execute commands in the same script?](http://superuser.com/questions/468161/howto-switch-chage-user-id-witin-a-bash-script-to-execute-commands-in-the-same)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use the sudo command in the script.

In the form:

```
sudo -u username command
```

the sudo command runs *command* as the user *username*.

If the script is being run as root, I don't think it will prompt for a password. Otherwise, this article discusses how to use [sudo with password in one command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line), and this article discusses how to use [sudo without password?](https://serverfault.com/questions/92893/sudo-without-password)

Comment: This is nice and easy, but is there a way to do this for a group of commands instead of one at a time?

Comment: write a bash script, make it executable `chmod +x script.sh` and then just `sudo -u username script.sh`

Comment: @Andrew I was wondering this myself and the following worked for me: sudo -u ic sh -c 'cmd1 && cmd2'

Comment: Also include the `i` option if you want to acquire the user's environment

Answer (score 12):

# I=like:

```
#test if running bash as a different user works
sudo -u nobody bash -c : && RUNAS="sudo -u nobody"

echo 1: $USER

#Runs bash with commands between '_' as nobody if possible
$RUNAS bash<<_
echo 2: \$USER
_

echo 3: $USER
```

# ./run

```
1: root
2: nobody
3: root
```

Comment: Could you add some explanatory text?

Comment: Manish explains in the suggested edit: https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1095251

Comment: Use '_' instead of _ to expand the variables within

Answer (score 8):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/93387/4377) is good, but the serverfault advice is slightly dangerous - would allow anyone to run anything as root!  So I'm posting here because I can't format the comment.

I would recommend using visudo to give the permissions you need as precisely as you can.  Type `visudo` and add a line like:

```
username hostname = NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/command1, full/path/to/command2
```

If you do need to run this same thing on many hosts, you could open it up with:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/command1, full/path/to/command2
```

But I would **not* use either:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or
    username hostname = ALL

The [sudoer man page](http://man-wiki.net/index.php/5:sudoers) has lots of gory details

Comment: Would it work for a command available to a particular user only ?

Comment: You can specify that only particular users can run the command (in the examples above, replace `username` with the username who should be able to run the command). If the executable you want to run is only executable by one particular user, that's fine too - just pass that username in the `sudo -u username commandline` line of the script.

Comment: @Manish.  Yes.  What the sudoers file says is "Allow this username on this host to run command1 without having to provide a password.

Answer (score 5):

This way, end of a script will be executed by different user (root).
Please note the `$[LINENO+2]` and `exit $?` calls. These are required to make the end of the script to execute just once and to preserve the exit code of the `sudo` call.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
echo $USER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

# pipe the rest of this script via a sudo call                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
tail -n +$[LINENO+2] $0 | exec sudo bash                                                                                                                                                                                                     
exit $?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
echo $USER
exit 1
```

Answer (score 4):

For sonarqube:

`sudo -u sonar /usr/bin/sonar start`

where `sonar` is the name of user used to run the command `/usr/bin/sonar start`

Answer (score 3):

not so sure about it, but if you want that ONLY the end of that script will run as a different user, you could add `su someuser` before the end of the script.

Am I missing something?

Hope that helps,

Regards

Comment: I think this is the most appropriate answer, having all other answers suggesting sudo, which is often not installed by default on some minimal linux installations.

Comment: `su someuser` will start a new shell, it won't execute the rest of the script.

Comment: Yeah this won't work, it'll just go into a new shell then do nothing forever, the rest of the script won't be executed

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need as the OP, I had a good sized shell script that needs to be run as root, but a good portion of which I need to have run as another user. My solution was to put the entire contents of script (both the part that needs to be run by root, and the part that needs to be run as "other_user") in an if/elif block:

```
if [ $USER = "other_user" ]
then
   ## Run commands as user other_user
   :
   exit
elif [ $USER = "root" ]
then
   ## Run some commands as root
   :
   ## Next, run this script as other_user
   sudo -i -u other_user $0 "$@"
   ## Then run more commands as root
   :
else
   ## Nobody else should run this script
   echo "Permission denied"
   exit 1
fi
```