# How to accpeting password by shell script

Tags: passwords, shell-script

As we know that, password must be inputted while switching user [**Username: test, Password: test**]

```
[user1@hosts ~] $ su test
Password: 
[test@hosts ~]$
```

Now I want to create a shell script (example: login.sh) to switch user without entering password.

My shell script is:

```
su - test
test   # The password of user test
```

But it still needs password entering.

How can the shell script accept the password?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/93405/51741), in this case `sudo` is the tool you need.

Comment: @Shadok That requires you to enter a password at some point. I guess the OP needs `expect`.

Comment: Thanks for @Shadok, but I don't think the answer is what I want. I just want to switch user by script, but execute command by another user.

Comment: Hi @slhck , I have finished my problem by using ssh. However, I think **expect** is a good idea. I don't use that command before, but I will have a try. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found another method to switch the user without password (Even if the new user needs password authentication).

That is using `ssh`

Alias file in **user1**:

```
alias tt="ssh test@127.0.0.1"
```

And cat the user1's id_rsa.pub to test's authorized_keys:
user1:

- user1: create ssh public key: **rsa_id.pub**

  > $ ssh-keygen -t rsa
  >
  > press yes if asking...
- upload the user1's public key to test's directory (this step needs input the password):

  > $scp id_rsa.pub test@127.0.0.1:/home/test
- add the **rsa_id.pub** into **.ssh/authorized_keys**

  > $ su - test
  >
  > Password
  >
  > $ cd $ cat rsa_id.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
  >
  > $ chmod 644 .ssh/authorized_keys

Then switch user by using `tt`

```
$ tt
Last login: Mon Jan 28 20:27:34 2013 from localhost
[test@host ~]$
```