# How to escape password in plink sudo command?

Tags: batch-file, sudo, escape-characters, plink

When trying to login with plink to a server I don't know how to pass the sudo password in the command correctly.

I use something like this:

```
plink -ssh -t <user>@<server> -pw <password> "echo -e <password>\n | sudo -S docker ... | cd <some path>"
```

The password contains 2 special chars - a ";" and a "*" char. In the first place the ";" char needs to be escaped with a "^" and a connection can be established. Then in the command I need to switch to sudo to use a docker command. Usually it should take the pass from the console. But somehow it seems that there a different escaping is needed. I tried some things and added single quotes around the password in the second place, tried it with and with the linebreak behind the pass but none of the things I tried worked. Anyone knows how to make it work?

Let's say an example password is: abc123;*

When I use this text in the bat-file:

```
SET password=abc123;*
plink -ssh -t <username>@<server> -pw abc123^;* "echo -e %password%\n | sudo -S docker exec -i <docker_container> <docker_container_path> |pwd"
```

What I would expect is that after this code the user would be in the docker container and a tomcat path would be displayed. But instead the current directory after the connect is displayed and below there are those lines:

```
[sudo] password for <user>: Sorry, try again
[sudo] password for <user>:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

I tried diffent approaches to escape the password for the plink command like:
`SET password=abc123\;\*` or
`SET password=abc123%%3B%%2A` or `SET password=abc123^;*`

but none of them worked.

Note: Unfortunately changing the user password or setting the linux server to "no password" is not an option.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Well yes, it works. Without the echo there wouldn't be the incorrect password attempt message.

Comment: That's pretty ambiguous answer. **Did you test it successfully** in SSH terminal?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Uhm, I think it works. I logged in with putty and tried that echo command. But all I get as feedback is incorrect password attempt. I also tried: echo <password> ^| ... If I use just the echo <password> I see the correct password when I escape the semicolon with \;.

Comment: So it does not work.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Ah ok, thx. Sorry, I didn't know. My Sysadmin skills are very limited. ;) Since there was a callback that the password is incorrect I expected something was passed and it was just about another syntax error or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo with password in one command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line)