# How to send sudo password in a shell script

Tags: shell, sudo, su

My shell script (don't have EXPECT, and is not possible) runs a shell script impersonating another user. Let's say the following script is named `toto1.sh` and is run with a user called `MYUSERNAME1`.

```
#!/bin/sh
su - MYUSERNAME2 ./app/sh/toto2.sh
```

My script stops, prompting a password request...

How can I send the password for `MYUSERNAME2`?

Comment: Consider setting up passwordless sudo for this particular case.

Comment: I can not, security question. I'm really stuck with the command su

Comment: Can't you run or schedule the script as `root`?

Comment: I do not have the right, the script is invoked by an external application that does not have to have full rights ...

Comment: To put it simply, I can only use the command su

Comment: As a general rule, it is better to avoid writing password down inside scripts.

Comment: i  know it, but this is my last solution ... how can I do it?

Comment: Wait a moment...you don't have `sudo`?

Comment: my administrator to add the user to sudoers

Comment: Your answer is not clear to me: do you have `sudo`?

Comment: yes, i have sudo

Answer (score 4):

If you have `sudo` available, the solution has already been posted in a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4327123/7659430) of [places](https://superuser.com/a/67766/700617):

```
echo <password> | sudo -S -u <user> <command>
```

From `man sudo`:

> -S, --stdin
>                Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal device.
>   The password must be followed by a newline character.

Comment: "The password must be followed by a newline character." - Useful info for scripts!

Answer (score 2):

#### Approach 1 - Read from file

You can save the password in a read-only file for the user and pass the contents to the sudo command.

This will avoid password being stored in shell history

```
# Save the password in the hidden file
echo "password" > ~/.password

# Update the permissions to allow only the user to read it
chmod 400 ~/.password 

# Pass the password over STDIN to sudo
☠ cortex ☠ [~] cat ~/scripts/login_file.sh
cat ~/.password | sudo -S su

# Execute the script
☠ cortex ☠ [~] bash ~/scripts/login_file.sh 
[sudo] password for cortex: 
☠ cortex ☠ [~]
```

#### Approach 2 - Save to temporary environment variable

With this approach, you need to enter on the shell or in the script.

```
☠ cortex ☠ [~] cat ~/scripts/login.sh 
my_password='password'                  # SET PASSWORD
echo "$my_password" | sudo -S su        # INVOKE sudo WITH PASSWORD
```

#### Combine with the script

Use any of the approaches mentioned above and authenticate `sudo`
Then invoke the commands with root access.

```
☠ cortex ☠ [~] cat ~/scripts/login.sh 
# SET PASSWORD
my_password='password'

# INVOKE sudo WITH PASSWORD
echo "$my_password" | sudo -S su;

# INVOKE COMMANDS WITH ROOT ACCESS
sudo -i <<'EOF'
    echo "Now i am $(whoami)"
    echo "$(id)"
EOF

☠ cortex ☠ [~] bash ~/scripts/login.sh 
[sudo] password for cortex: Now i am root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

#### Cut the clutter with `ALIAS`

Make the sudo to internally get the password and authenticate itself.
You need not require to input the password over STDIN every time

```
# Create the alias with the Approach 1
☠ cortex ☠ [~] echo "alias sudo=\"cat ~/.password | sudo -S\"" >> ~/.bashrc 

# OR Create the alias with the Approach 2
☠ cortex ☠ [~] echo "alias sudo=\"echo \"password\" | sudo -S\"" >> ~/.bashrc 

# Re-load the environment
☠ cortex ☠ [~] . ~/.bashrc 

# Use sudo directly - No need to pass on password everytime
☠ cortex ☠ [~] sudo whoami
root
```