# supply password for sudo and openconnect in one alias command

Tags: linux, sudo

I want to make an alias for openconnect, the alias is

```
echo "password" | sudo openconnect server --user=username --passwd-on-stdin --no-cert-check
```

Everything works fine but my problem is that each time I need to enter my password because I'm using `sudo`. What can I do to also supply the password for `sudo` in this alias?

I have seen
[this question](https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line)
but it didn't help.

Comment: Try `echo "<sudo password>" | sudo -S sh -c "echo \"<password>\" | openconnect server..."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

`echo "<sudo password>" | sudo -S sh -c "echo \"<openconnect password\" | openconnect server --user=username --passwd-on-stdin --no-cert-check"`

replacing  with the password needed for root and  with your openconnect password.

This should work because you first pipe in the sudo password to sudo itself (using -S as per your linked question, to take in the password via stdin) and then executing (as root) another command - this is what `sh -c` does (when followed by a string that is your command). We append our command to `sh -c` which includes piping in the openconnect password to openconnect - at this point, openconnect is working as root and so doesn't need sudo before it.

While I don't use openconnect, I tested with `echo "mypassword" | sudo -S sh -c "whoami | xargs -i echo {}` to test piping the value from `whoami` which tells me `root`, confirming the sudo works. You may get a line into stdout (your terminal) stating to enter in the password, but it will still work - you can ignore this line if you specified it in stdin.

Comment: I don’t know how to thank you!