# How do I run a sudo command on a remote machine using ssh?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, bash-scripting

I am trying to remotely run a shell script on an ubuntu host.

I can ssh to the machine using me@host just fine.

On the remote machine I can run sudo commands without needing to input a password.

I can run a shell command on the remote host just fine using rsh

So now I put a sudo command and I get an error

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

the command I run is the following:

```
ssh user@hostIPAddress  "cd /opt/somewhere && sh -v -v ./install.sh"
```

the install.sh contains one command that requires a sudo command

```
#!/bin/bash
  
sudo pm2 stop someprocess
```

How do I get around this error?

Comment: What is the output of `ssh user@hostIPAddress 'sudo whoami'`? Is this the same user and machine you meant when you said, "I can run sudo commands without needing to input a password"?

Comment: I get root when I run the command you suggested. when I run the whoami without the sudo, I get the user I sshed as

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. I created /tmp/install.sh with `#!/bin/bash¶echo I am $(sudo whoami)` and ran `ssh myserver  "cd /tmp && sh -v -v ./install.sh"` but it worked fine.

Comment: ok, let me check again.

Comment: So if your `ssh user@hostIPAddress 'sudo whoami'` worked without requiring a password, then we have a proof point that you *can* run (at least *some*) sudo commands through ssh successfully, right?  That would indicate to me that the problem is likely somewhere in the `sh -v -v install.sh`.  As bitinerant said, give his simple-test install.sh a try.  If it works, then we need to figure out what in the other `install.sh` is causing password request.  Try that `sudo pm2 stop someprocess` in the test file and see if you can isolate the problem to that.

Comment: I was targetting the wrong machine. Sorry about that. ssh -t user@hostIPAddress  "sudo whoami" still asks for password. I think I need to fix the asking of password first. Correct?

Comment: As described in the answer from Kamil Maciorowski, you can just add `-t` to the ssh command and it will prompt you for the password.

Comment: ssh user@IP  "whoami" works with out asking for password

Comment: The `-t` is so `sudo` can prompt you for a password.

Comment: I want to eliminate the need to enter a password. That is the problem I need to solve

Comment: Then you need to edit `sudoers`, but with care. See [How to run an application using sudo without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/a/39294). Note "You can replace the path to an executable with "ALL" if you choose, giving you complete passwordless sudo."

Comment: that is exaclty what I was looking for.

Comment: so now how do I give you credit for the response?

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because it states "on the remote machine I can run sudo commands without needing to input a password" and then the accepted answer is exactly "how to run a sudo command without a password". The explicit question is "How do I get around this [`a terminal is required`] error?" and the accepted answer has nothing to do with it. Please [edit] and **make the question coherent with what you accepted**. I will revoke my vote and delete my answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want `sudo` to prompt for a password, after understanding the security implications, you can edit the `sudoers` file. However, it is not safe to edit the file directly. Instead, use:

```
sudo visudo
```

To allow running your specific program without a password, add a line to `sudoers` in the format:

```
YOURNAME ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/pm2 stop someprocess
```

Above, replace `YOURNAME` with your login on that system, and `/path/to/pm2` with the full path to that program (output of `which pm2`).

If you want to allow running `pm2` passwordless with *any* parameters, not just   `stop someprocess`, then delete those last 2 words from the line.

For more on editing `sudoers`, see [How to run an application using sudo without a password](https://askubuntu.com/a/39294) and `man sudoers` and `man visudo`.

Answer (score 7):

#### Changing the behavior of `ssh`

When you run `ssh` without a command and there is a local pseudo-terminal, the tool allocates a pseudo-terminal on the remote side automatically. Usually you access an interactive remote shell this way, so allocating a terminal is the right thing to do.

When you provide a remote command to `ssh`, it assumes the command is not interactive. It doesn't provide a pseudo-terminal to the command. This happens in your case, `sudo` finds no terminal.

You can explicitly tell local `ssh` to allocate a pseudo-terminal on the remote side:

> `-t`
> Force pseudo-terminal allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple `-t` options force tty allocation, even if `ssh` has no local tty.

<sup>([source](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#t))</sup>

```
 ssh -t user@hostIPAddress  "cd /opt/somewhere && sh -v -v ./install.sh"
```

Note when you do this, you can no longer tell the stdout and stderr of `./install.sh` apart locally. Read the "broader picture" part of [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1557724/432690).

---

#### Changing the behavior of `sudo`

`sudo` suggests alternative solutions that depend solely on `sudo` itself:

> `sudo`: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the `-S` option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

These are:

- read from standard input: `sudo -S` (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/67766/432690));
- configure an askpass helper: `sudo -A` (see the second part of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1351876/432690)).

Both require an argument to `sudo`, so you would need to change the script. It's easy to lessen security by using any of these options. **Strongly prefer `ssh -t`.** Note in general [`sudo` may be configured not to work without a terminal anyway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122616/108618).

Comment: ssh -t user@hostIPAddress  "sudo whoami" still asks for password

Comment: @reza Your explicit question is "How do I get around this error?" and what you call "error" is `sudo: a terminal is required …`. My answer solves exactly this.

Comment: ssh user@IP  "whoami" works with out asking for password

Comment: I wish I could rephrase my question but it is too late to change the title ...
ssh -t user@IP  "sudo whoami"
[sudo] password for ubuntu:

Comment: `ssh -t ` changed my life. So many useless tutorials whereas this is so simple! Lesson of the day: **`RTFM`**